# Query to increment values based on a value from another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with below schema   `+-------------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field                   | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id                      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| parent_id               | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| name                    | varchar(255)     | NO   | UNI | NULL              |                             |
| disp1     | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| disp2 | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| created                 | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                             |
| updated                 | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| node_e             | tinyint(1)       | YES  |     | 1                 |                             |
| node_priority           | int(5)           | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
+-------------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+`

I run below query to get the desired data :

```
select id,node_priority,parent_id from node where parent_id in (Select distinct parent_id from node as n) order by parent_id asc;
```

which gives below output :

```html
 +-----+---------------+-----------+
| id  | node_priority | parent_id |
+-----+---------------+-----------+

|  17 |             0 |         2 |
|  18 |             0 |         2 |
|  19 |             0 |         2 |
|  20 |             0 |         2 |
|  21 |             0 |         2 |
| 216 |             0 |         3 |
|  23 |             0 |        22 |
|  24 |             0 |        22 |
|  25 |             0 |        22 |
|  26 |             0 |        22 |
|  27 |             0 |        22 |
|  29 |             0 |        28 |
|  30 |             0 |        28 |
|  31 |             0 |        28 |
|  32 |             0 |        28 |
|  33 |             0 |        28 |
|  35 |             0 |        34 |
|  36 |             0 |        34 |
|  37 |             0 |        34 |
|  38 |             0 |        34 |
|  39 |             0 |        34 |
|  40 |             0 |        34 |
|  41 |             0 |        34 |
|  42 |             0 |        34 |
|  44 |             0 |        43 |
|  45 |             0 |        43 |
|  46 |             0 |        43 |
|  47 |             0 |        43 |
|  48 |             0 |        43 |
|  49 |             0 |        43 |
|  50 |             0 |        43 |
|  51 |             0 |        43 |
|  58 |             0 |        52 |
|  60 |             0 |        52 |
|  66 |             0 |        52 |
|  77 |             0 |        52 |
|  95 |             0 |        52 |
|  96 |             0 |        52 |
| 106 |             0 |        52 |
| 117 |             0 |        52 |
| 128 |             0 |        52 |
| 137 |             0 |        52 |
| 141 |             0 |        52 |
| 164 |             0 |        52 |
|  55 |             0 |        53 |
|  56 |             0 |        53 |
|  57 |             0 |        53 |
|  59 |             0 |        58 |
|  61 |             0 |        60 |
|  62 |             0 |        60 |
|  63 |             0 |        60 |
|  64 |             0 |        60 |
|  65 |             0 |        60 |
|  67 |             0 |        66 |
|  68 |             0 |        66 |
|  72 |             0 |        66 |
|  73 |             0 |        66 |
|  74 |             0 |        66 |
```

My main Goal :

I want that for same value of parent_id column , value of node_priority should be in incremental order from 0 to the number of row having same parent_id.

so that output would be like below :

```html
+-----+---------------+-----------+
| id  | node_priority | parent_id |
+-----+---------------+-----------+

|  17 |             0 |         2 |
|  18 |             1 |         2 |
|  19 |             2 |         2 |
|  20 |             3 |         2 |
|  21 |             4 |         2 |
| 216 |             0 |         3 |
|  23 |             0 |        22 |
|  24 |             1 |        22 |
|  25 |             2 |        22 |
|  26 |             3 |        22 |
|  27 |             4 |        22 |
|  29 |             0 |        28 |
|  30 |             1 |        28 |
|  31 |             2 |        28 |
|  32 |             3 |        28 |
|  33 |             4 |        28 |
|  35 |             0 |        34 |
|  36 |             1 |        34 |
```

I am not able to write a query for the same.
Kindly help.

Comment: you could use ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT *** )) to achieve your outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mysql you can achieve this using the user defined variables something as

```
select
id,node_priority,parent_id 
from (
 select 
 id,
 @rn:= if(@prev_parent = parent_id,@rn+1,0) as node_priority,
 @prev_parent:= parent_id,
 parent_id
 from node,(select @prev_parent:=0,@rn:=0)x
 order by parent_id
)x
```

Also

```
where parent_id in (Select distinct parent_id from node as n)
```

is not needed in the above query.

To update you can use the following

```
update node n1 
join (
  select 
  id,
  @rn:= if(@prev_parent = parent_id,@rn+1,0) as node_priority,
  @prev_parent:= parent_id,
  parent_id
  from node,(select @prev_parent:=0,@rn:=0)x
  order by parent_id,id
)n2 on n1.id = n2.id
set n1.node_priority = n2.node_priority;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f203/1

Comment: Hi, the purpose is to update the node_priority column as per above values.

Comment: Yes the above query will show the node_priority in incremental order for each parent_id and with some slight modification it could be written as update query. First check if the above query returns expected result. You may change the order by as `order by parent_id,id` so that for each parent_id it will also do the ordering for id

Comment: Yes the query is returning the desired result. and query returns output sorted by id by default.

Comment: Well that is not guaranteed since the data is unordered unless you explicitly provide order by clause.

Comment: ok will use order by id as well to ensure ordering for id. Can you please help me with update query

Comment: its also not guaranteed because the order of operations isn't and can get messed up. doesn't happen a lot but ive seen it before

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
SELECT ID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY parent_id ORDER BY parent_id) - 1 AS node_priority,
    parent_id
FROM (
     SELECT id,parent_id
     FROM node
     WHERE parent_id in (SELECT DISTINCT parent_id
                         FROM node))
```